# Custom BigInteger JSON serializer

Tags: java, spring, jackson, objectmapper

I am trying to implement a custom JSON serializer class to display object `BigInteger` values as string in the JSON response.

I have implememented a custom serializer class

```
public class CustomCounterSerializer extends StdSerializer<BigInteger> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5440920327083673598L;

    public CustomCounterSerializer() {
        this(BigInteger.class);
    }

    public CustomCounterSerializer(Class<BigInteger> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(BigInteger value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        BigInteger valueJson = value==null ? BigInteger.valueOf(0) : value;
        jsonGenerator.writeString(valueJson.toString());
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that I want to handle the `null` object values using the overridden method and pass `0` to the JSON string and not `null`.

I have written a JUnit test for this:

```
public class CustomCounterSerializerTest {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        objectMapper = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testCustomSerializerWithNullValues() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        obj.setNonNullValue(BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        String obj_ = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        assertThat(obj_).isNotNull();
        assertTrue(obj_.contains("\"nonNullValue\":\"" + BigInteger.valueOf(1).toString() + "\",\"nullValue\":\""+ BigInteger.valueOf(0).toString() +"\""));
    }

}
```

It fails as it contains `null` and not `nullValue:"0"`.

But the `null` value of the object always goes to no args constructor and even like `this(BigInteger.class)` does not use my method and prints `null`.

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't assume fields are serialized in a particular order.

Comment: I am using @JsonSerialize and specify the class as a serializer for that attribute. I am not assuming the order. I want the behavior according to the value.

Comment: Your assert is expecting `nonNullValue` before `nullValue`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell Jackson that it should use your serializer
even for null values. You do this by using `@JsonSerializer`
also with the [`nullsUsing`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html#nullsUsing()) parameter.

In your MyObject class it would look like this:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomCounterSerializer.class,
               nullsUsing = CustomCounterSerializer.class)
private BigInteger nullValue;
```